# jQuery retain focus on input unless focus on another input

Tags: jquery, focus

I have an input that I would like to have retain focus as the user clicks buttons on the page, but allow focus to move to other text inputs on the page. I can have the input (in my example, 'typeText') always retain focus, but the check to see if the element gaining focus is an input doesn't seem to work.

```
$('#typeText').blur(function () {
    if ($(':focus').not('input:text')){
        $(this).focus().select();
    }          
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <div id="containerBoxx">
    <input class="inputClass" type="">

    </div>

$('#containerBoxx').click(function () {
if (event.target.tagName !== "input") {
 var inputs, index; inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
 for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
 // deal with inputs[index] element. }      
 })
```

Comment: This would require me to have the 'inputClass' on all inputs that I would like to have ignored but simultaneously trys to focus all of them at once

Comment: Just change it  to tagName; event.target.tagName

Comment: @Dan Wier, updated answer, let me know if anything missing.

Comment: This essentially works. I set the container element for the body to a class like 'containerBoxx', and then if the tagName isn't 'INPUT', set focus back on the specified control. I was unaware of tagName, thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help.